# Getting file paths of loaded layers in QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am very new to GIS, QGIS and Python. 
I am using QGIS 2.0 and I would like to develop a QGIS plugin that would display the raster layers of the main window in order to allow for some specific interaction. I have a very hard time getting this to work! 
I generated the skeleton of my plugin through plugin builder, and changed the [moduleName]2dialog.py file to try to display the main window layers.

I have two questions :

1. Is it possible to get the layers?
2. Can I draw it inside a GqsMapCanvas inside my plugin GUI, or do I need another object?

This is the code I have for now, which generates an error :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from qgis import core, gui, utils
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvasLayer

mc = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mc.mapRenderer().layerSet()
if not layers:
    self.ui.displayFileNameTextEdit.setText("No layer to display.")
else:
    for layer in layers: #layer is one id
        self.ui.qgsMapCanvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self.ui.qgsMapCanvas.setLayerSet( [ QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer) ] )
        self.ui.qgsMapCanvas.refresh()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my problem, thanks to Matt and to this link : http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Display-raster-layer-on-own-Map-Canvas-td5002935.html

Here is how I do it, inside the [moduleName]2dialog.py file generated by the plugin builder plugin :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFile, QFileInfo
from qgis import core, gui, utils
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvasLayer
from qgis.utils import iface

layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
for each_layer in layers:
    fileName = each_layer
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    self.layer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.layer)
    self.canvas = self.ui.qgsMapCanvas
    self.canvas.setCanvasColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
    self.canvas.setExtent(self.layer.extent())
    self.canvas.setLayerSet( [ QgsMapCanvasLayer(self.layer) ] )
    r = QgsRubberBand(self.ui.qgsMapCanvas, True)
    self.canvas.setCurrentLayer(self.layer)
    self.canvas.setVisible(True)
    self.canvas.refresh()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of the layers in the table of contents and perform actions like so:

```
legend = self.iface.legendInterface()
layers = legend.layers()
for each_layer in layers:
    if each_layer.type() == "RasterLayer":
        print each_layer.id()
        print each_layer.name()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get each layer's filename? (e.g. with absolute path) If yes, I can do what I want.

Comment: try each_layer.source(), each_layer.name() will return the name of the layer as it is in the TOC.

Comment: Actually could be each_file.dataUrl(), have a look round the QGIS API yourself here http://qgis.org/api/2.0/

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have my solution. Posting it right now!